# Formulas for rendering raised graphic buttons

Tags: windows, winapi, graphics, gdi+, gdi

With each new version of Windows, native desktop applications are at the mercy of its changing visual styling.

If the application wants to take control of its own styling and present a consistent visual interface over time, it must draw its own controls, and foremost amongst these is buttons.

In my view, the most attractive Windows buttons were in WinXP and Win7, with rounded corners and a pattern of gradients, creating a subtle and raised bevel.

Where can I find a formula for rendering this type of button, in terms of common GDI primitive operations such as rounded rectangles and gradient shading operations?

Comment: You won't get anti-aliased rounded rectangles with GDI, in case that's what you're aiming for.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is stuck on this, the best I've found after hours of searching is the following article and demo:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4208/XP-Style-Button

Thanks to Valeria Bogdevich for this contribution in 2003.

It emulates XP-style buttons using only GDI+ primitives, and is written in C# but the Graphics primitives are the same.

It's based on a series of DrawLine and FillRectangle primitives with several LinearGradientBrush objects blended on top of each other.

Must have taken quite some effort to deconstruct.  The results look pretty good.